# ViewModel QueryException using objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hy Guys.

I have 2 entities: "Interactions" and "Orders", which has many "Interactions".

On View, I wanna a different class (like `<tr class=@cssClass>`) for the Orders which has interactions unread. So I created a ViewModel.

My ViewModel:

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public Order Order{get;set;}
    public bool isRead{get;set;}
}
```

My controller (I'm working with repositories):

```
var orders = orderRepo.All();
var viewModel = orders.Select(order=> new orderViewModel
{
    Order = order, '<------------'
    isRead = order.Interactions.Any(x => x.Read == true),
});
return View(viewModel);
```

If I take out the `Order = order,` It works fine. But with this code I'm getting this error:

> QueryException was unhandled by user code. Could not instantiate: Models.OrderViewModel
>
> InnerException: When casting from a number, the value must be a number less than infinity
>   InnerException: Make sure the source type is convertible to the destination type.
>
> ---

If, instead of use the objects I use their properties, it works fine:

```
ViewModel:
public int IdPedido { get; set; }
public string CategoryOrder { get; set; }
public string ModuleOrder { get; set; }

Controller:
var viewModel = orders.Select( order => new OrderViewModel{
CategoryOrder=Order.Category,
ModuleOrder=Order.Module,
...});
```

What am I missing? I'm not understanding what should be convertible. Or isn't possible to use Objects on ViewModel, only Properties?

If it's a usable information, I'm using the Nhibernate ORM.

Tks guys!

---

**EDIT**

Based on @elspiko question, I realized that Order and Orders didn't have the same type. So I set orders: `IEnumerable<Order> orders = pedido.Repo.All();` And now it's working.

I thought it would work before editing. Why was it considered different types?

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't look right, it should be:

```
var viewModel = orders.Select(order=>new OrderViewModel
{
   Order = order, '<------------'
```

But i'm assuming thats just a typo?

It might have something to do with lazy loading, if you put a debugger on the select statement, what type does order have? Is it some form of proxy object?

Comment: I edited the code. It really was. Tks. So, orders {Nhibernate.Linq.Query<DTOS.Entities.Orders>}. It's a form of proxy.

Comment: Order's type is DTOS.Entities.Order